# Tomcat Connection issue with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat

My program runs fine if i am running it as Application. 
When i run on server it gives an error.
Before implementing the hibernate and maven my tomcat was working ok and i was able to see the results.

Hibernate.cnf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3305/petclinic?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">25</property>
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">14400</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">3600</property>


    <mapping class="com.rt.Beans.Owner"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

My Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>PetClinic</groupId>
<artifactId>PetClinic</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>PetClinicMaven</name>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

```
<!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>antlr</groupId>
<artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
<version>2.7.7</version>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- Hibernate annotation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Error

```
 WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@62533a4b -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to  acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2359)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
... 17 more
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your error:

```
ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Indicates that this is *not* a Hibernate/Tomcat issue. **This error appears, when Java fails to initiate a connection on a given port.** Since your config contains a reference to this address and port:

```
127.0.0.1:3305
```

I would suggest testing it by using telnet:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3305
```

The most likely result is that if you try connecting to this MySQL server from the host where your Tomcat is running, your telnet connection will fail, proving that this problem is not related to your application. From that on, the best is to check:

- first, the availability of your server (connecting from local)
- firewall settings, to ensure that remote applications can connect too

Comment: i am able to run the application using test class. 
running it as application. 

but, for running on tomcat server only i get the error.

thanks

Comment: This does not make sense. Could you show your test code, and all parts of it that established the connection with the DB?